# How to add quick links without links?

Tags: quick-links

I'm looking how to add some Quick Links without Links.
I have different bricks, but for some, I don't have the links already. But I want to show the bricks, so that the user know that I didn't forgot it.
For the moment, I have links that go to a page like "sorry, this page is not ready yet". But the user wastes time beacaus he's redirected on an useless other page.

I know that is possible because one of my colleagues succeeded, but he doesn't remember how.
And it's possible without any code (he's not able to).

I tried :

- supress link and save but I can't save ;
- put the link of the actual page but there's waste of time to refresh the page ;

In a second time, I'm looking how to change the color of some of bricks : like this I have one color for the bricks with a links, and an other color for the bricks without links.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge, it's not possible to add links without actual link in OOTB Quick Links web part.

As a work around you can create list with necessary column like Title,URL,Color and you can build similar UI like Quick Links web part using [**View Formatting**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-formatting) using JSON where you can handle rendering based on field value so in your case you can generate Hyperlink only when URL field is not empty.

You can find similar JSON sample at below link but of course you need to adapt it according to your requirement to not render anchor tag if URL field is empty

https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting/tree/master/view-samples/icon-link-tiles

Here you can also achieve your second requirement which showing different color based on some condition